# Is there any way can know if the thread is created success or failure?

Tags: c++, stdthread

I am using `std::thread` to create a thread, but looks like there is no API can tell if this operation success or failure. Is there any way to know this information?

Comment: The `std::thread` constructors raise `std::system_error` on failure.

Comment: `looks like there is no API` Are you aware of exceptions?

Comment: If it doesn't throw an exception, it succeeded.   If it does throw an exception, it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `std::thread` throws an exception in the case of a failure.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

> Exceptions 3)
> [std::system_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) if the thread could not be started.
> The exception may represent the error condition
> std::errc::resource_unavailable_try_again or another
> implementation-specific error condition.

If you use OS-specific threading mechanics, you may look up their respective (C) APIs:
[Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread)
[Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

See [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) for `std::thread` constructor:

> `std::system_error` if the thread could not be started.

This is the general practice in C++. When constructor fails, you raise an exception, otherwise your object is in an awkward invalid state, which is something standard library usually avoids.

Answer (score 1):

There are two popular approaches to determining success of unreliable operations in  modern programming languages.

- Have a returned status code or readable error code, which indicates whether the operation was successful. This is the older approach, used in C programs and hence the POSIX interfaces many of them use. With this style, functions and methods have the semantics of only *trying* to perform an operation. On return from the function or method you know that an attempt has been made, but you do not know whether it was successful.
- Throw an exception if, and only if, the operation failed. This is the newer approach, used in well written C++ programs and the C++ standard library. With this style, functions, methods and constructors have the semantics of *doing* an operation. On return from the function, method or constructor you know that the operation has been successfull.

So, in your particular case, return from the thread constructor means the thread was successfully created, and there is no need to check a status code.